# Alter Lambda Expression to go one level deeper

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Suppose I have a method like this:

```
public void MultiDropDown<T>(Expression<Func<T, DropDownModel<DropDownItem>>> expression)
{

   // Here i want to get more specific with the expression selector
   // Suppose it was passed like this: 
   //                                  MultiDropDown(x => x.MyDropDown);
   // I need to alter `expression` and go deeper:    x => x.MyDropDown.Title;
   // And then use the new expression for other stuff...
}
```

#### Solution

Thanks to svick !

```
public void MultiDropDown<T>(Expression<Func<T, DropDownModel<DropDownItem>>> expression)
{
        // 1. Build a new expression and select the final property
        Expression<Func<DropDownModel<DefaultDropDownItem>, object>> childExpression = x => x.Title;
        // 2. Extract property name
        var propName = (childExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        // 3. Create a MemberExpression selection from parent's Body
        var expressionProperty = Expression.Property(expression.Body, propName);
        // 4. Finally create a Lambda Expression
        var refinedExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, object>>(expressionProperty, expression.Parameters);
}
```

Operations 1. and 2. were done just for avoiding "Title" string and relying on Strongly Typed model instead.

Comment: Can't you just use `Select(x => x.MyDropDown.Title)`?

Comment: No I'm strongly typing it to `DropDownModel<DropDownItem>`.

Comment: See: [How to: Modify Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx)

Comment: I've tried but didn't figure out how to go deeper. Only to add additional conditions like `And` `Or` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to create an expression that takes the `Body` of your query and accesses the given property on it. Then you need to build back the lambda expression. The whole thing looks like this:

```
var titleExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(
    Expression.Property(expression.Body, "Title"), expression.Parameters);
```

Comment: Brilliant answer !!. Can you please take a look at the solution if there are no pitfails :)

Comment: @Christian Yeah, it's fine. Though if you're on C# 6.0, I would prefer `nameof(DropDownModel<DropDownItem>.Title)` instead.

Comment: Good spot :). You made my day YAY!