# How to rebuild a lambda expression to start one level deeper?

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression

I created a generic method that accepts a member access expression identifying a grouping key, just as one would pass to `IQueryable<T>.GroupBy`.

```
private static IQueryable<ObjectWithRank<T>> IncludeBestRankPerGroup<T,TGroupKey>(this IQueryable<T> q, Expression<Func<T, TGroupKey>> keySelector)

class ObjectWithRank<T> {
    public T RankedObject { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

The `IncludeBestRankPerGroup` method is a variation of my `IncludeRank` method that just takes an `IQueryable<T>` and applies a rank to each element by wrapping it in `ObjectWithRank<T>`, returning an `IQueryable<ObjectWithRank<T>>`.  I then want to group by the `keySelector` and select the best ranked element per group.

This requires me to convert a lambda expression from form 1 to 2 so I can pass it to `IQueryable<ObjectWithRank<T>>.GroupBy`:

1. `(T x) => x.GroupingProperty`
2. `(ObjectWithRank<T> x) => x.RankedObject.GroupingProperty`

Note that I cannot just change the root object type of the `keySelector` from `T` to `ObjectWithRank<T>`, because the `ObjectWithRank<T>` class is not exposed in the public method that calls `IncludeBestRankPerGroup`. The user of the API just provides an `IQueryable<T>`, and receives back an `IQueryable<T>` with the highest ranking items per group, so they never see that `ObjectWithRank<T>` is used under the hood.

I managed to perform the conversion with the following code, but it only works for simple member access expressions.  For example, it can convert an expression like `x => x.GroupingKey` to `x => x.RankedObject.GroupingKey`, but it won't work with a two-level deep member access expression where I'd have to convert something like `x => x.SubObject.GroupingKey` to `x => x.RankedObject.SubObject.GroupingKey`.

```
private static Expression<Func<ObjectWithRank<T>, TGroupKey>> RebuildMemberAccessForRankedObject<T, TGroupBy>(Expression<Func<T, TGroupKey>> keySelector)
    {
        Expression<Func<ObjectWithRank<T>, T>> objectAccessExpression = x => x.RankedObject;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjectWithRank<T>, TGroupKey>>(
            Expression.Property(objectAccessExpression.Body, (keySelector.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo)
            , objectAccessExpression.Parameters
        );
    }
```

The above seems like a hack where I first create a member access expression that access the `T RankedObject` property of the `ObjectWithRank<T>`, then tack on the provided `keySelector` member access expression. I'm not sure if there's a simple way to get this to work.  It seems like Expression.Property only allows drilling down one property at a time, so maybe I need some kind of loop to rebuild the expression from the top, drilling down one property at a time.

There's a similar question here that does have a simple solution, but goes one level deeper on the opposite end of the expression, which isn't what I'm trying to do.
[Alter Lambda Expression to go one level deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732763/alter-lambda-expression-to-go-one-level-deeper)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace the root of an expression with a recursive lamba that drills down in the member expression until it reaches the parameter expression, replaces the parameter expression with the new root expression at that deepest level, then unwinds the call stack replacing each member expression's Expression with the updated inner expression all the way back to the top, then create's a new lambda with the updated expression and parameter expression set for the new root.

```
private static Expression<Func<TInNew, TOut>> UpdateExpressionRoot<TOut, TInOld, TInNew>(Expression<Func<TInNew, TInOld>> newRoot, Expression<Func<TInOld, TOut>> memberAccess)
{
    Func<MemberExpression, MemberExpression> updateDeepestExpression = null;
    updateDeepestExpression = e =>
    {
        if (e.Expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            var updatedChild = updateDeepestExpression((MemberExpression)e.Expression);
            return e.Update(updatedChild);
        }
        if (e.Expression is ParameterExpression)
            return e.Update(newRoot.Body);
        throw new ArgumentException("Member access expression must be composed of nested member access expressions only.", nameof(memberAccess));
    };
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInNew, TOut>>(updateDeepestExpression(memberAccess.Body as MemberExpression), newRoot.Parameters);
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
class Car
{
    Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

class Manufacturer
{
    string ID { get; set; }
}

Expression<Func<Car, string>> groupKeySelector = x => x.Manufacturer.ID;
Expression<Func<ObjectWithRank<Car>, Car>> rankedObjectSelector = x => x.RankedObject;

var rankedGroupKeySelector = UpdateExpressionRoot(rankedObjectSelector, groupKeySelector);

//rankedGroupKeySelector.ToString() == "x.RankedObject.Manufacturer.ID"
//Essentially this replaced ParameterExpression {x} in x.Manufacturer.ID with MemberExpression {x.RankedObject}.
```